# WinForms TreeView - how to manually "highlight" node (like it was clicked)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I would need to know how to let the programatically selected node make graphically in the state "selected" like the user clicked on it. SelectedNode only makes this one internally selected. Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry but i needed to comment on answers 1 and 6
should be node[2] not node (2)
answer #4 put node[2] the reason i'm saying this is because i can't comment on the existing answer as i lack rep points. More importantly, i think we all check the first answer as it has the most points. when we try the code and it doesn't work we move on to the lower answers or another post. This is a 10 year old question. It's not like I'm going to get any points here :D I just hope you'll fix that error in those two answers and delete my post so that whoever decides to try their code, won't face such issues. tha

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason it does not show as highlighted is due to the tree view not having focus.  This is in a button click event on my test form:

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode = TreeView1.Nodes(2);
TreeView1.Focus();
```

Which highlights the node properly.  if you remove the `Focus();` call it doesn't highlight until you click into the tree view (anywhere in the tree view, not necessarily on to the node that you want to be selected).

Comment: Also the property HideSelection can be used. If set to false the highlight will be shown regardless of focus.

Comment: There are drawbacks to this. We have been using similar approach however find that if the user cancels the drag the wrong node is selected. We tried tracking last node selected this and reselecting in dragleave but then the list scrolls to the original item if you drag out.

Comment: @Goran: This is what I was looking for! Why is this `true` by default??

Answer (score 5):

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode.BackColor = SystemColors.HighlightText; // This will work
```

Above solutions will only set the focus on it but will not change the highlight view of it.

Comment: This actually worked for me, Thanks!      I changed the code a little bit:    `TreeView1.SelectedNode.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;`
`TreeView1..SelectedNode.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;`

Comment: This is nice because it works even when a programmatically selected node shows `TreeView1.SelectedNode.IsSelected == false`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me for .net 3.5:
Set the treeview component's **DrawMode** property to: **OwnerDrawAll**
Then in the **DrawNode** event write the following:

```
 if (((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0) && (!MyTreeView.Focused))
     e.Node.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
else
     e.DrawDefault = true;
```

And in the **BeforeSelect** event have:

```
if (MyTreeView.SelectedNode != null)
    MyTreeView.SelectedNode.ForeColor = Color.Black;
e.Node.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got to work:

```
void myProcedure()
{
  // Hookup a DrawMode Event Handler
  this.myTV.DrawNode += myTV_DrawNode;
  // Set DrawMode and HideSelection
  this.myTV.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
  this.myTV.HideSelection = false;

  // Make sure the TreeView has Focus
  this.myTV.Focus();
  // Make sure the TreeView is Selected
  this.myTV.Select();
  // If the TreeView has a Node, I want to select the first Node to demonstrate.
  if (this.myTV.Nodes.Count > 0)
  {
    // Make sure the node is visible
    this.myTV.Nodes[0].EnsureVisible();
    // Make sure the Node is Selected
    this.myTV.SelectedNode = myTV.Nodes[0];
  }
  // Make sure the SelectedNode IS the Node that we programmatically want to select.
  textBox1.Text = this.myTV.SelectedNode.Text;
  // if we display sanityCheck1 string, it actually is the correct node.text
  // Make sure .NET runtime knows the Node is selected
  textBox1.Text += "  is Selected = " + this.myTV.SelectedNode.IsSelected.ToString();
}
```

Following up:  **laalto** answered the How to HighLight the TreeView.Node.  The following code in the DrawNode Event Handler, from **samball**'s answer, properly highlights the TreeView.Node based on its Selected State.

```
private void myTV_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
  // first, let .NET draw the Node with its defaults
  e.DrawDefault = true;
  // Now update the highlighting or not
  if (e.State == TreeNodeStates.Selected)
  {
    e.Node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    e.Node.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
  }
  else
  {
    e.Node.BackColor = ((TreeView)sender).BackColor;
    e.Node.ForeColor = ((TreeView)sender).ForeColor;
  }
}
```

Platform = C# .NET 4.5 in Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps you or not but check the taborder of the the page and make sure that the tree view control has tab order of 0

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode = TreeView1.Nodes(2);
this.ActiveControl = TreeView1;
```

This works for me (.net 4.7)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying Win32 control supports this (think it's `TVIS_DROPHILITED`), but I can't see the same functionality exposed through the `TreeView` control.

As theraneman says, you could fake it with the `TreeNode.ForeColor` and `BackColor` properties...

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar issue and wanted to have a `TreeView` node selected (highlighted) **on form load**.
Maybe someone has the same problem, too.

I first tried Pondidum's solution. Without success.
But then I found the solution in another thread: Simply set the `TabIndex` of the `TreeView` to 0.
In that case **you don't need to set the focus**. Just choose the node that should be selected by using `SelectedNode` and set the `TabIndex`. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but can you not change the background color of that node?

Comment: That would be problematical, I would need to ensure its set back when other node is selected etc.

Comment: Trying this I find that I get a lot of flicker of the tree when dragging.