# Setting TreeView.SelectedNode doesn't highlight the node

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

If I click on a node in my TreeView, that node is highlighted. But if I set it using TreeView.SelectedNode, then the node is selected and on my next event it is still selected.

But it isn't highlighted.

What do I need to do to get highlighting?

thanks - dave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms TreeView - how to manually "highlight" node (like it was clicked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838807/winforms-treeview-how-to-manually-highlight-node-like-it-was-clicked)

Comment: TreeView must have the focus to show the blue highlight.  Consider setting its HideSelection property to *false*.